# Does a webservice is a standalone or can use outside classes

Tags: c#, web-services

Can a web service use other classes that I have in a project or should it be standalone and use only it's own methods?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you actually tried it before asking? Of course it can. Do you have any actual problem or it's only a generic question?

Comment: I did on a local host, but I didn't know if it will work on a real server, plus, I didn't know what the conventions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a web service can use other classes that I have in the project ?

YES it can. You can also return your custom class object, after serialization. Its very unusual that you would see webservice interacting with primitive types only *(internally)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can create instances of other classes and use them to perform work.

Any class in the same project or a referenced project should be usable, subject to the usual access modifiers.

You'll either need to include a using statement.  Following example assumes you want to use `SomeClass` which resides in `MyAssembly.SomeLibrary`:-

```
using MyAssembly.SomeLibrary;


// in code block somewhere
var thing = new SomeClass();
```

or fully qualify the name of the class.

```
   var thing = new MyAssembly.SomeLibrary.SomeClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking in terms of best practice rather than "is this technically possible".  The answer depends on the class you want to use I suppose, but in general it is acceptable to use any other classes or libraries you want in a web service as this will not affect the client being able to consume the service (i.e. using LibraryA on the service side does not mean client 1 has to also have LibraryA installed to use your service).

It is possible to reuse those classes service side (in Visual Studio this is done by ticking the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" box when you configure a service reference and then adding a reference to the appropriate project / dll), but I would generally advise against it as it can confuse matters - not all clients will have access to those dlls when consuming your service.